# Const list has non-const items. Why?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a test with `const` `Widget` list.

```
const passing = [
  Item(),
  Item(),
];
```

But test fails. I found out that items are non `const`! Their `hashCode`s are different as if they are `(new)`. Why?

[image]

[image]

#### Reproducing

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test('Non equal consts', () {
    final one = constList[0];
    final another = constList[1];

    expect(one, another);
  });
}

const constList = [
  ConstItem(),
  ConstItem(),
];

class ConstItem extends Widget {
  const ConstItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Element createElement() {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your reproduction is accurate? `one` and `another` have equal `hashCode` values in DartPad.

Comment: It's not that this `const` `List` has non-`const` elements; the elements surely are immutable.  What you're observing is that the elements are not *canonicalized*.  I can reproduce this when I run it locally, and it seems to be tied to `ConstItem` deriving from `Widget`.

Comment: I would recommend [filing an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/).

Comment: @hacker1024 It is correct sample. I have edited the post and provided image with proof

Comment: Closing the loop: OP filed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107767, where it was explained that it's normal for debug builds: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/debugging#widgets-marked-const-that-should-be-equal-to-each-other-arent